# use the same array every time i make recursive javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I use the same array every time I make a recursive call?

I don't wont to splice the array , I need to work in the same array just change fromIndex and endIndex of the array.

```
function BinarySearch(values, searchedValue) {
    var middleIndex = Math.floor(values.length / 2);
    var middleValue = values[middleIndex];

    if (middleValue === searchedValue) return true;
    else if (middleValue < searchedValue && values.length > 1) {
        return BinarySearch(values[0,middleIndex], searchedValue);
    }
    else if (middleValue > searchedValue && values.length > 1) {
        return BinarySearch(values.splice(0, middleIndex), searchedValue);
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: If you don't `splice` your array, try to think: **is there another way for the recursive algorithm to progress?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the recursion algorithm must progress, I converted the array's modification to an update of the two indexes (`start` and `end`):

- In the function's signature
- In the calculation of `middleIndex`
- In the recursion's termination condition
- In the recursion's "progress" (choosing the first or the second half of the array)

```js
function BinarySearch(values, start, end, searchedValue) {
  var middleIndex = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
  var middleValue = values[middleIndex];

  if (middleValue === searchedValue) return true;
  else if (middleValue < searchedValue && end-start > 1) {
    return BinarySearch(values, start, middleIndex, searchedValue);
  } else if (middleValue > searchedValue && values.length > 1) {
    return BinarySearch(values, middleIndex, end, searchedValue);
  } else return false;
}

let input = [1, 2, 5, 12, 25];
console.log(BinarySearch(input, 0, input.length-1, 5));
console.log(BinarySearch(input, 0, input.length-1, 8));
```

Please let me know if something's still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make your implementation without changing the algorithm and without mutating the array. You just need to keep track of where you are when recursing, just pass this information to an inner local recursive function, hummmm recursivelly.

```
function BinarySearch(values, searchedValue) {
  function doSearch(left,right) {
    var middle = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
    var middleValue = values[middle];
    if (middleValue === searchedValue) 
      return middle;
    if ((right-left) <= 1)
      return -1;
    else if (middleValue > searchedValue) 
      return doSearch(left,middle);
    else if (middleValue < searchedValue)
      return doSearch(middle,right);
    else 
      return -1;
  }
  return doSearch(0,values.length);
}
```